# Comparison theory of projections

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

if $E$ and $F$ are two projections in von Neumann algebra $M$, how to construct a unique central projection $P$ such that $PE \sim PF$?. The construction I am not getting?

Comment: The proof I am not getting from Kadison and that is why I want to know an intuitive idea of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the proof is "take all central projections $P'$ such that $P'E\sim P'F$ and join them to obtain $P$". In more technical terms, this is achieved by considering a maximal family of pairwise orthogonal projections.

Comment: But how do you know the family you are considering for using Zorn's lemma is non-empty??

Comment: If there is no nonzero projection with the property, you already have that $P=0$ (which always works). If there is a nonzero $P'$, then you can use Zorn.

Comment: Thanks indeed, here I was stuck. Now it is clear.

Comment: Great! :) $\ \ \ $